# Undefined Method Error in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**models/collaborators.rb:**

```
class Collaborator < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :wiki

  def wiki_collaborations
  end
end
```

**controllers/wikis_controller.rb:**

```
class WikisController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @user = current_user
    if @user.admin?
      @wikis = Wiki.all
    elsif @user.premium?
      @wikis = Wiki.where(private: false) | @user.wiki_collaborations | @user.wikis
    elsif @user.standard?
      @wikis = Wiki.where(private: false) | @user.wiki_collaborations
    else
      @wikis = Wiki.where(private: false)
    end
  end

  def show
    @wiki = Wiki.find(params[:id])
    authorize @wiki
  end

  def new
    @wiki = Wiki.new
  end

  def create
    @wiki = current_user.wikis.new(wiki_params)
    if @wiki.save
      flash[:notice] = "Wiki was saved."
      redirect_to @wiki
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "There was an error saving the wiki. Please try again."
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = current_user
    @wiki = Wiki.find(params[:id])
    @user_emails = User.where.not(id: current_user.id || @wiki.users.pluck(:id)).map(&:email)
    authorize @wiki
  end

  def update
    @wiki = Wiki.find(params[:id])
    authorize @wiki

    if @wiki.update(wiki_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Wiki was updated."
      redirect_to @wiki
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "There was an error saving the wiki page. Please try again."
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @wiki = Wiki.find(params[:id])

    if @wiki.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "\"#{@wiki.title}\" was deleted successfully."
      redirect_to wikis_path
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "There was an error deleting the wiki page."
      render :show
    end
  end

  private
  def wiki_params
    params.require(:wiki).permit(:title, :body, :private)
  end
end
```

I tried to access `http://localhost:3000/wikis`.

I get the following error.

[image: error message]

Comment: You defined method `wiki_collaborations` on Collaborator model, but invoked this method for User instance. It's logical that you got error in this case.

Comment: The error message really says it all.

    `@user.wiki_collaborations`

This expression tries to call a method `wiki_collaborations` on a `@user`.

But `@user` does not have such a method at all.

On the other hand, we can see that `wiki_collaborations` is defined in the class `Collaborator`.

Review your design and code.

Comment: `Wiki.where(private: false)` always returns true.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you've not defined `wiki_collaborations` method for user.

You can [delegate](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html) it to `User` like,

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  delegate :wiki_collaborations, to: :collaborator
end
```

Btw, be aware of `|` is not same as `||`.

Comment: According Collaborator model we can't say exactly does User have `has_many` or `has_one` association. Your approach will fire if there is `has_one` association on User model, but it won't work if there is `has_many`, because there is the question which one collaborator should be method delegated.

Comment: I just make an intuitive estimation, and possibly I'm not going to be mistaken -))